# Is a 'list of cherry cokes' a 'list of cokes'?

Tags: java, generics

I get "Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<CherryCoke>` to `List<Coke<?>>`"

It looks like a 'list of cherry cokes' is not a 'list of cokes'. This is counterintuitive.
How can I create that 'xs' anyway, if it has to be a `List<Coke<?>>` and I have to have a subclass of `Coke<Cherry>` ?

```
class Taste { }
class Cherry extends Taste { }

abstract class Coke<T extends Taste> { }    

class CherryCoke extends Coke<Cherry> { }

class x {
  void drink() {
    List<Coke<?>> xs = Arrays.asList(new CherryCoke());
  }
}
```

Comment: The most useful acronym to remember here is [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs). `Coke<?>` isn't anything specific, so you can't say "a list of cokes is a list of cherry cokes," but you can use `? extends Coke<?>`. See the question I linked for more information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right - a 'list of cokes' is not a 'list of cherry cokes' - a list of 'things that extend coke' is a 'list of cherry cokes' though.

You probably want to define `xs` as `List <? extends Coke<?>> xs = Arrays.asList(new CherryCoke());`

Comment: That's actually unnecessary. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, `List<CherryCoke>` and `List<Coke<?>>` are not the same thing.

But that's not really the issue here. It's not necessary to type `xs` as `List<? extends Coke<?>>`. You could have just as well created a new `List<Coke<?>>` and then added a new `CherryCoke` to it.

The error simply has to do with the compiler inferring `asList`'s type parameter `T` incorrectly. If you specify `T` yourself it compiles:

```
List<Coke<?>> xs = Arrays.<Coke<?>>asList(new CherryCoke());
```

Comment: This works as well. Which solution you want to use may depend on the underlying program this code is a part of.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Coke<?>> xs = Arrays.asList(new CherryCoke());
```

`List<CherryCoke>` is not a sub type of `List<Coke<?>>`(List of Coke of anything).

you should define upperbound of your generic type.

```
List<? extends Coke<?>> xs = Arrays.asList(new CherryCoke());
```

Comment: What's an *upper*-bound? I'd change that word to "constraint"... that's the official name, IIRC, and it's even inherently meaningful, IMHO... a "bound" sounds like theres an array under the hood, which there isn't.

Comment: @corlettk check here please http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html

Comment: Pass the sauce please. I need to eat my words, and they're sour! ;-)